# If using nodejs Express .use, why is the path suffix ignored and how to avoid?

Tags: node.js, express

If using nodejs package Express, a handler bound by `app.use('/intern',handler);` is also invoked on pathes like `http://host/intern.html`.

Why is that, and how to prevent it?

Comment: The prefix is removed by design, and will help you make things more modular.  Is your question on the prefix, or how to write regex so that `/intern.html` won't be matched by `/itern`?

Comment: My question is why a handler mounted by  `.use('/intern',...`, where `/intern` is called a 'path' all around the internet, does handle a path `/intern.html`, that is obviously not placed within the path `/intern`. You clarified it a little by talking about regex, so I guess it is not meant to use a 'path logic' altogether in the syntax of `.use`, but merely a regex matching. However, `/internals` is not matched, so this is just akward.

Comment: It's by-design.  Don't think as requested paths as always analogous to a filesystem.  The truth is that this is rarely the case when building server-side web applications.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't get what the exactly logic is. I seems to be 'match the given prefix and remove that prefix' then. However, why does'nt that apply to `/internals`?

Comment: That I don't know.  You should add that to your question.

Comment: Or I may just ask here: What `.use` argument make a handler respond to anything below the path `/intern`, and `/intern` itself, without matching anything outside this path?

Comment: You can use regex for that.  There are examples here:  http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use

Answer (score 1):

According to the Express developers, `.use` slices the `path` on `/` as well as on `.` in Express 3.x. This 'feature' was not well documented, and considered bad, and removed by 4.x.

So by using Express 4.x, `.use` can be used as expected, only matching on `/` delimited path segments.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that,

Generally, this is useful as the common case is to want to route all paths beginning with a prefix through the same code. So you could, for example, have an "admin" portion of your site and do something like `app.use("/admin", checkUserIsAdmin);` to protect that whole set of paths. It's there because prefix matching is more commonly used compared to exact matching.

> and how to prevent it?

In your situation, it sounds like you just need to make sure you add your static handler to the app before you add the other route.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.use('/intern', handler);
```

If "/intern" is just a single page, use `app.get('/intern', handler` instead of `app.use` and that will also solve your collision confusion problem.

Comment: My question was not about why a prefix like `/intern` can be used to mount stuff on it, but why `/intern.html`, which is not a part of the path `/intern` of course, does trigger the handler for `/intern` (while `/internals` would NOT.). The path `/intern.html` should be handled by the handler mounted on `/` and serves the file `intern.html`.

Comment: @dronus If that isn't your question, then you should change your question title because that's exactly what your question title says.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should have read 'suffix'. I change that.

Comment: Adding the static handler this way would totally change the priority of the handlers. If there would be a file `intern/index.html` in the html directory, it would be served at `/intern`, circumventing for example a login barrier for `/intern` provided by `handler`.

Comment: I've explained how it works and one option. I don't know your entire app or your URL patterns and preferences. I'm just providing you with some common options. If you can't find a clear way to express how your app uses routes in express, it's a sign you may be doing things that are confusing or unusual and your app will be hard to debug.

Comment: It turned out the express makers found it bad too, and removed this 'feature' from 3.x to 4.x. So after updating, I'm happy.